# Jabra Evolve 65 headset speakers only work when connected via USB cable

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, headset

I have a Jabra Evolve 65 headset with Bluetooth dongle:

[image]

One year or so it worked perfectly, then I stopped using it for a long while. Today I tried them again and they had the following problem.

When the headset is connected via USB cable, it appears as **2- Jabra EVOLVE 65** and everything works fine. Clicking the volume buttons on the headset makes the Windows volume bar pop up correctly.

When the headset is connected via Bluetooth, it appears in the audio devices list (Sound settings) as **2- Jabra LINK 360**; microphone works fine but headset speakers don't receive any sound from the PC.
The audio messages from Jabra (*"PC connected"*, etc) can be heard, though.
Also, the volume buttons on the headset don't work.

I have updated both headset and dongle via Jabra Direct to the latest firmware, with no avail.

OS is Windows 10.